# How to format rest Json response in soapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am getting JSON body from REST response with escaped characters shown below. How to format JSON response in soapUI using groovy script?

From:

```
{
  "employee": "{\"name\":\"John\", \"age\":30, \"city\":\"New York\"}"
}
```

To:

```
{   "employee": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "New York"   } }
```

Comment: Request the service provider or developer.

Comment: Try with JSON.parse(yourJson);  Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

A simple string-replace would do the job:

```
def escapedString = '''{"employee":"{\"name\":\"John\", \"age\":30, \"city\":\"New York\"}"}'''
def unescapedString = escapedString.replaceAll("\\\\", "")

System.out.println unescapedString
```

This produces:

```
{"employee":"{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}"}
```